# How to compare a date from outer query with date in inner query using MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, inner-query

I have customers, jobs, orders and dates as columns. Customers can have multiple orders per job and of course multiple jobs given a certain date range.

What I am trying to do is figure out how many "new" orders there are within a certain date range. Meaning, if a job has 5 orders, it should only return 1 order.
Here's a short example of a database table, desired result, and the query I have been trying to work with thus far.

```
+-------+-------+---------+------------+
| CusID | JobID | OrderNo |  OrderDate |
+-------+-------+---------+------------+
|   1   |   10  |    25   | 2021-12-22 |
|   1   |   10  |    26   | 2022-02-09 |
|   3   |   5   |    28   | 2022-01-10 |
|   3   |   6   |    29   | 2022-01-11 |
+-------+-------+---------+------------+
```

There are 4 rows of orders with their associated `JobID`. The query should return 2 rows since order 25 and order 26 are both associated with `JobID` 10, only 1 can be counted as "new", while `OrderNo` 25 falls outside of the outer queries date range.

Here is the query I am trying to use, based on the date being `>=` to the first of the year. I want to be able to use the `OrderDate` from the outer query, to compare with the `OrderDate` from the inner query. If there is a `JobID` with an `OrderDate` that is less than the current rows `OrderDate` that order is NOT new and should return the `JobID`, thus making the inner query false and filtering out the row.

```
SELECT * FROM orders
WHERE OrderDate >= '2022-01-01' 
AND JobID NOT IN 
(SELECT JobID FROM orders WHERE inner.OrderDate < outer.OrderDate)
```

Expected result

```
|   3   |   5   |    28   | 2022-01-10 |
|   3   |   6   |    29   | 2022-01-11 |
```

Comment: Is the purpose to find the newest order for a job within the date range? Then I don't understand why order 26 does not match. This can be done with a subquery or cte and row_number.

Comment: it is to find the first order for a job that is new within the date range. Not to include orders for jobs that have later orders.

Comment: What is the date range supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`row_number`](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-row_number-function/) to rank the orders for each job. Put that in a subquery and only accept the <strike>newest</strike> oldest? order for each job.

```
select custid, jobid, orderNo, orderDate
from (
  select
    *,
    row_number() over ( partition by jobid order by orderDate asc ) as oldest
  from orders
) a
where a.oldest = 1
  and orderDate >= '2022-01-01'
```

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d7777b48d4ed5e8a7fe10386b935f6b1)

Comment: Thanks, but if it includes order 26 then it doesnt really solve the problem. Also I believe the same outcome could be achieved with a SELECT DISTINCT(jobid) with ordering the table by orderdate descending.

Comment: @Zackattack There's nothing in your description which would exclude 26, it is within your date range. [You can do this with `select distinct on` in Postgres](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=dd8b1254805bfea865bdc4a4a202c2ed) I don't know about MySQL.

Comment: @Schwern Apart from the fact that 26 is not the first order for the job, and the first order for the job (25) is before the given date.

Comment: @nnichols You ask for "new orders" which I assume would be the *last* job in the range; the newest one. You could clarify that by adding an example of multiple orders for a job where one *is* picked. Either way, you can adjust this answer to your needs by changing the order.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is heading in the right direction you just need to apply the alias to the outer table so it is uniquely identifiable -

```sql
SELECT *
FROM orders `outer`
WHERE OrderDate >= '2022-01-01'
AND JobID NOT IN
    (SELECT JobID FROM orders WHERE OrderDate < `outer`.OrderDate);
```

Depending on the number of rows included in your time range, and the average number of orders per job, you may want to aggregate first -

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT JobID, MIN(OrderDate) AS MinOrderDate
    FROM orders
    WHERE OrderDate >= '2022-01-01'
    GROUP BY JobID
) o
WHERE JobID NOT IN
    (SELECT JobID FROM orders WHERE OrderDate < o.MinOrderDate);
```

Assuming it is possible for a job to have multiple orders on one date, you might want to consider using OrderNo instead of OrderDate for your comparison -

```sql
SELECT *
FROM orders `outer`
WHERE OrderDate >= '2022-01-01'
AND JobID NOT IN
    (SELECT JobID FROM orders WHERE OrderNo < `outer`.OrderNo);
```